# Передача UTM-метки из URL браузерной строки якорем к ссылке на кнопке

Tags: tilda

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы *в конструкторе Tilda* для передачи UTM-метки из URL браузерной строки в UTM-ссылку на кнопке, *использовался знак "&" вместо знака "?" перед UTM.*

В настоящее момент, при переходе из какого-либо источника на страницу сайта, в адресе есть UTM-метка, они добавляются с использованием символа "?" перед первой меткой.

Вот пример:

```
https://adressaita.ru?utm_source=vk&utm_medium=public&utm_campaign=25sek&utm_content=tovar
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при переходе по любой кнопке на этой странице сайта подставлялась эта UTM метка, но вместо символа "?" использовался символ "&".

Новый формат URL-ссылки после нажатия на кнопку на сайте (в кнопке зашита ссылка) должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
https://vk.com/app7070938_-218765339#s=65321d55c50d74098542e1dc&utm_source=vk&utm_medium=public&utm_campaign=25sek&utm_content=tovar
```

Comment: ответ: никак. [параметры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B) начинаются с символа `?`, разделитель параметров — символ `&`. то, что вы вообразили, не должно распознаваться ни одним соответствующим стандартам http-сервером,

Comment: Сервис ТаргетХантер распознаёт такие UTM.

Comment: дополнение: собственно, http-запрос с таким url не должен даже быть отправлен http-клиентом. просто сами проверьте, нарисовав файлик с нужным вам url, открыв его в http-клиенте, и щёлкнув по такой некорректной ссылке. вы должны получить ошибку от http-клиента.

Comment: `https://vk.com/app7070938_-218765339#s=65321d55c50d74098542e1dc&utm_source=vk&utm_medium=public-ac&utm_campaign=alfa-course&utm_content=tovar`

Comment: и вы не понимаете отличия url, приведённого в вопросе, и в последнем комментарии? тот, что приведён в комментарии, вообще не содержит параметров. он содержит [«якорь»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#%D1%8F%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8C). который вообще http-клиентом не должен передаваться на http-сервер: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067491/is-the-anchor-part-of-a-url-being-sent-to-a-web-server

Comment: Я, к сожалению, не силён в терминологиях таких.. Мне просто нужно параметры UTM, которые указаны в браузерной строке, прикрепить к ссылке, которая в кнопке. Я не знаю, как это сделать, по этому тут написал. Если знаете как, подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо

Comment: понятно. ситуация [«ошибка молотка»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy). думаю, вам надо сформулировать в тексте вопроса (нажав [edit]) вашу исходную проблему.

Comment: Спасибо! Надеюсь сейчас я правильно сформулировал..